# Show 2 COUNT syntax on one SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

i have a table from the book list

```
+---------+-------------------------+------------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| ID      | Title                   | Writer           | Publisher   | year  | Status   |
+---------+-------------------------+------------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| S00001  | philosophy the intro    | K. Bertens.      | Kanisius    | 2018  | BOOKED   |
| S00002  | Karl Marx: Das Kapital  | Karl Marx        | el-Classica | 2017  | READY    |
| S00003  | Karl Marx: Das Kapital  | Karl Marx        | el-Classica | 2017  | READY    |
| S00004  | Karl Marx: Das Kapital  | Johann Luwiss    | Mediatama   | 2015  | READY    |
| S00005  | Marxis                  | Karl Marx        | Photoem     | 2019  | READY    |
| S00006  | Karl Marx: Das Kapital  | Karl Marx        | el-Classica | 2017  | BOOKED   |
| S00007  | philosophy the intro    | K. Bertens.      | Kanisius    | 2018  | READY    |
+---------+-------------------------+------------------+-------------+-------+----------+
```

first and can show the count from duplicate of title and Writer group by TITLE and Writer but i cant show COUNT from the status where its 'READY' on every single row.

the result should be like this

```
+-------------------------+-----------------+-------+------+
| Title                   | Writer          | Ready | stock|
+-------------------------+-----------------+-------+------+
| Marxis                  | Karl Marx       | 1     |    1 |
| Karl Marx: Das Kapital  | Johann Luwiss   | 1     |    1 |
| Karl Marx: Das Kapital  | Karl Marx       | 2     |    3 |
| philosophy the intro    | K. Bertens.     | 1     |    2 |
+-------------------------+-----------------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Well, show us what you *can* do

Comment: or just sit back and let us do all the work for you

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    title,
    writer, 
    sum(status = 'READY') ready,
    count(*) stock
from books
group by title, writer
```

`sum(status = 'READY')` is a nice MySQL shortcut to count how many records satisfy the inner condition (`status = 'READY'`). It relies the fact that, in numeric context, MySQL evaluate a true condition as `1` (and a false condition as `0`).